# Contact form 7 ajax response true/false based on some condtion

Tags: customization, plugin-contact-form-7

I want to integrate custom logic after submit form.

I want to store contact form data in the custom table, if data is stored then the response would be true otherwise false.

I am using **wpcf7_before_send_mail** hook

Please help me how can I do this.

My sample code here

function save_data_to_project_after_form_submit( $contact_form ) {

```
// Save data to my custom table

if(data save to database){
  // Same as currently working and mail send
} else {
  // giving error message something went wrong and mail should be not send.
}
```

}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_data_to_project_after_form_submit', 10, 1 );

Comment: I am not sure to understand, on which condition you don't want to store data ? to store all forms, you can use that https://contactform7.com/save-submitted-messages-with-flamingo/

Comment: Try to ALWAYS include your code. How can we help you if we can't see what you have tried? Also, if you only want to store the data, use Flamingo like @mmm commented.

Comment: I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party (5 years...) but for future generations stumbling upon this question, you can use `&$abort` in `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook to prevent mail from sending:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','your_function',10,3);

function collect_email($wpcf7_data, &$abort, $object){ //pass reference
    /* your code here */
    if($data_saved == true){
        $object->set_response("Data saved");
    }
    else {
        $abort = true;
        $object->set_response("Data not saved");
    }
}
```

If you want to have even more control over ajax response, you can use feedback filter:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_feedback_response', function( $response){
    /* do your stuff with $response array */
    return $response;
});
```